# Why does calling the KFold generator with shuffle give the same indices?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

With sklearn, when you create a new KFold object and shuffle is true, it'll produce a different, newly randomized fold indices. However, every generator from a given KFold object gives the same indices for each fold even when shuffle is true. Why does it work like this?

Example:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
kf = KFold(4, n_folds=2, shuffle = True)
​
for fold in kf:
    print fold
​
print '---second round----'
​
for fold in kf:
    print fold
```

Output:

```
(array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]))
(array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]))
---second round----#same indices for the folds
(array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]))
(array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]))
```

This question was motivated by a comment on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34731698/1435522). I decided to split it into a new question to prevent that answer from becoming too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new iteration with the same KFold object will not reshuffle the indices, that only happens during instantiation of the object. `KFold()` never sees the data but knows number of samples so it uses that to shuffle the indices. From the code during instantiation of KFold:

```
if shuffle:
    rng = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    rng.shuffle(self.idxs)
```

Each time a generator is called to iterate through the indices of each fold, it will use same shuffled indices and divide them the same way.

Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py) for the base class of KFold `_PartitionIterator(with_metaclass(ABCMeta))` where `__iter__` is defined. The `__iter__` method in the base class calls `_iter_test_indices` in KFold to divide and yield the train and test indices for each fold.

Answer (score 0):

With new version of **sklearn** by calling `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold`, **KFold generator** with **shuffle** give the different indices:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

print('---first round----')
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    
print('---second round----')
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Out:

```
---first round----
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1 3] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [0 1 2] TEST: [3]
---second round----
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [0]
TRAIN: [0 2 3] TEST: [1]
```

Alternatively, the code below iteratively generates same result:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.choice([0, 1], 10, p=[0.5, 0.5])
kf = KFold(2, shuffle=True, random_state=2022)
list(kf.split(data))
```

Out:

```
[(array([0, 1, 6, 8, 9]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 7])),
 (array([2, 3, 4, 5, 7]), array([0, 1, 6, 8, 9]))]
```